# How to deploy a Python program to a computer that's offline?

Tags: python

I have a small python app I've developed for file validation.  I need to deploy it to a server that has no outside internet access.  It utilizes a number of libraries (pandas, glob, os, datetime, pyodbc and numpy).

I was able to install Python 3.8.5 on the server and I attempted to use Pyinstaller to wrap everything including the libraries into a nice exe that could run on the server but it did not work.  I am trying that again using the --onefile flag.  Error message below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BDWtoStuckyValidation.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
dateutil: No module named 'dateutil'
```

The server is completely offline - I cannot simply use PIP to install the libraries that are missing.  Additionally, my work computer is VERY locked down so I also cannot simply download WHL files or similar and manually install them on the server.  Anything that has to be transferred to the server would need to be downloaded on my personal laptop, transferred to my work laptop via bluetooth and then to the server via the network.  I did just run pip download for my needed modules on a machine with internet access, bundled the whl files into a tar.gz file, transferred that to the server in question and it still wouldn't install when attempting to run pip install tar.gz  Update: I unzipped the tar.gz file and attempted to install some WHL files manually, it got stuck on pandas, attempting to download something or connect to pypi.org, which it obviously can't.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The pyinstaller exe “did not work” - you’ll have to be a lot more specific that this - run from the commandline, put full error messages into your question.

Comment: @cardinalsfan - this is literally what containers are made for. To package up applications and be able to deploy them in any environment - regardless of network status. Please do a bit of research on 'containerization'. If you can run 'docker' - you can run your 'container'. Docker is just one option for containerization - so please check what options work best for your use case.

Comment: Pyinstaller should do the job. If you are familiar with it, I'd recommend going forward with that and we can help you get it done. Otherwise, a more generic solution to make applications easily transferrable is packaging them using Docker (the currently most popular "containerization" tech, as my pre-poster mentioned).

Comment: “*my work computer is VERY locked down so I also cannot simply download WHL files or similar*” How *exactly* are you expected in your day to day activities to write Python code without being able to install dependencies…? Are you expected to re-invent the wheel every time you want to use any pre-existing library?? Having to file transfer from a personal machine is a screaming red flag.

Comment: @balmy - when I run from command line I get errors saying unable to import dependencies and a list of the modules missing.

Comment: Show the full error messages as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: @esqew - that's a great question.  I'm not a dev, I'm a BA stuck doing dev work.  I work for a bank, everything is very locked down and I am not granted access when I ask for it, even with manager approval.

Comment: Then you should not try to circumvent the security measures (at least it sounds like that).

Comment: @MichaelButscher - question updated with error message

Comment: @cardinalsfan If you’re stuck doing dev work, you need to get dev access. What you’ve got now is NOT at all sustainable nor is it wise to be transferring files to and from your personal devices. If you’re in such a locked-down environment, why would they allow you to transfer and execute arbitrary executables from your personal devices anyway? Doesn’t that sound like a big liability? Is it possible your previous efforts have failed because of security measures in place?

Comment: @cardinalsfan “*am not granted access when I ask for it, even with manager approval.*” If this is true, the core of this question is *not* technical, but political/interpersonal. You really should be escalating this before your use of file transfer from untrusted machines lands you in hot water. If your manager tasks you with driving a nail, but gives you no tools, would you try to drive it with your hand?

Answer (score 1):

The process you described should work, but you need to ensure that you get all of the indirect dependencies (the things that your direct dependencies depend on).  A good way to do that is via a tool like pip-compile (part of pip-tools), where you can declare your direct requirements in a requirements.in file and have it figure out the complete list of dependencies and versions (written in to requirements.txt, generally).  Once you have that list, you can download all the appropriate wheel files and proceed just as you described.

The reason that it would not work with your .tar.gz file is that pip expects a .tar.gz file to be a source distribution for a single package, rather than a tarball of a bunch of different wheel files for many packages.